# Using pg_dump to get the ddl of child table

Tags: postgresql

I have a log table which have several child tables inherit it 。but my question
is hard to  describe。Let is begin.

**--1 Enviroment**

PostgreSQL Version: 9.0.3

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5

**--2 parent table and child table**

```
 Schema |            Name             | Type  | Owner  |  Size   |  Description   
--------+-----------------------------+-------+--------+---------+----------------
 suplog | tbl_log        | table | suplog | 0 bytes | qq自更新日志表
 suplog | tbl_log_201205 | table | suplog | 59 GB   | 
 suplog | tbl_log_201206 | table | suplog | 58 GB   | 
 suplog | tbl_log_201207 | table | suplog | 57 GB   | 
 suplog | tbl_log_201208 | table | suplog | 51 GB   | 
 suplog | tbl_log_201209 | table | suplog | 39 GB   | 
 suplog | tbl_log_201210 | table | suplog | 36 GB   |
```

tbl_log is parent table , and all the xxx__yyyymm is child table and inherit 
  table tbl_log。

And I use the following sql  create child tables:

```
create table tbl_log_201210 ( like tbl_log including all ) inherits ( tbl_log );
```

**--3 add column table**

Then for some reason we want to add a column both in the parent table and child tables.
We just need a command , as following:

```
Alter table tbl_log add column address character varying(255) ;
```

**--4 pg_dump child table**

Now , I need  to get the create table statement of a child ,so I use pg_dump get the ddl。

```
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1921 -E UTF8 -t "suplog.tbl_log_201210" -s -v suplog > suplog.tbl_log_201210.ddl
```

From the above command, To my surprised, the create table command of the file suplog.tbl_log_201210.ddl 
does not contain the column "addres" which is a new column added by "ALTER TABLE" command.

**--5 query view pg_attribute**

```
suplog=> select attname,attislocal from pg_attribute where attrelid='tbl_log_201210'::regclass
and attname='address';
     attname     | attislocal 
-----------------+------------
 recommend_appid | f


we can see the column attislocal of view pg_attribute of that table show 'f'。
```

I don't know why , is that a bug？

Comment: Thanks for specifying the commands run, Pg version, etc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dump command only asks for the schema of the child table. The `create` for the child does not contain any columns but just `inherits`:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    inherits parent
);
```

What is surprising about that?

### Edit

The use of the `like` parameter decouples both tables. They are not parent and child. Check the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

It can work if you do that in two separate steps. First `create like` and then later `alter table inherit`

[Similar question answered by one of the developers](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/BUG-7583-Problem-using-INHERITS-and-LIKE-td5726624.html)

Comment: Just note my question carefully， and you will find the dump file miss the column which added later.

Comment: And I use the following sql  create child tables:
  create table tbl_log_201210 ( like tbl_log including all ) inherits ( tbl_log );

Comment: You're right. Deleted my answer. I was looking at the *parent*; while @francs is dumping the *child* and expecting it to change when a column is added to the parent. It won't, since the child still inherits the parent, and the fact that the parent has one more column doesn't change the definition of the child at all.

Comment: @decouples ,yes you are right, I use the two steps as you suggest, the dump file is ok now. 
But i'm still puzzled， because I use the following sql create child table .
"create table tbl_log_201210 ( like tbl_log including all ) inherits ( tbl_log );"  
The sql specify both the inherits and including attribute.

Comment: @decouples, so why we can't do that in just one step?

Comment: @francs Good question. But the main question is why do you need to make a inheritance relationship and also create hard columns? That only justifies when you will insert data into what will be the future child to make transformations before creating the relationship. If you do it in one only step what is the point? What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2):

9.0.3 is seven bug-fix releases behind, in addition to mention two major versions behind. Someone had posted and since deleted an answer show that this works as expected on 9.2. I note that 9.0.7 includes [this commit](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/ab060c74ba0f0767237e7a3bc6022a84e177abab):

> **Fix pg_dump for better handling of inherited columns.**
>
> Revise pg_dump's handling of inherited columns, which was last looked at
>   seriously in 2001, to eliminate several misbehaviors associated with
>   inherited default expressions and NOT NULL flags.  In particular make sure
>   that a column is printed in a child table's CREATE TABLE command if and
>   only if it has attislocal = true; the former behavior would sometimes cause
>   a column to become marked attislocal when it was not so marked in the
>   source database.  Also, stop relying on textual comparison of default
>   expressions to decide if they're inherited; instead, don't use
>   default-expression inheritance at all, but just install the default
>   explicitly at each level of the hierarchy.  This fixes the
>   search-path-related misbehavior recently exhibited by Chester Young, and
>   also removes some dubious assumptions about the order in which ALTER TABLE
>   SET DEFAULT commands would be executed.
>
> Back-patch to all supported branches.

The release notes indicate that this was added to deal with default handling, but I suspect this patch addresses your issue as well. Could you upgrade to 9.0.10 and see if this behavior persists?

Comment: thanks,I also note this release note, From the above it is about default value, but my case is different,so don't know why, I also doubt it's a bug of pg_dump.

Comment: may be upgrade the version to postgresql 9.0.7 can solve the problem.

Comment: He (Craig) deleted his answer because his understanding of it was wrong. See his comment in my answer.

Comment: @francs Although the upgrade to the last minor version is a must, your problem is the one I pointed in my edited answer.

Comment: @willglynn  I test the case in PostgreSQL 9.2.1, it's the same result.So maybe it's not a bug.